# Magento 2 what is the use of indexer backlogs?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, error, reindex, index

When we run the php bin/magento index:status command it throws the complete view of the indexer.

In Below screenshot you can see the backlogs are way higher. I am trying to understand what is the use of it.  Does it mean those indexes are showing errors? Or will process those items later?

[image]

What does it indicate?  If it is related to errors then where do i see those errors?  Is there any specific log file?

Any help would be appreciated!